# What is the right way to do columns in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make rows above like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7kb6.png) but i got a problem with it

[Here is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALzAZ.png)

And there is my code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="images col">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="" src="images/Layer%206%20copy%202.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="info col">
    <h2>waleed mahmoud mostafa</h2>
    <h2>living in cairo</h2>
    <h2>student</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The correct markup is: row > col * n

Comment: Explanation: you need a row with x columns inside. If you're going to a new line, make another row

Comment: By typing it columns instead of coloums .... But on the matter first, you define first your row, then your cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want centered image then use offset and text-center class

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="images col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="image text-center">
                <img class="" src="images/Layer%206%20copy%202.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <h2>waleed mahmoud mostafa</h2>
            <h2>living in cairo</h2>
            <h2>student</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no i want it to look like the first image if you saw it , i the triangle image to be in one row and the other div with the info class to be beneath the image

Comment: have you tried my example please have a look
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNBUFMG09WZ4

Comment: well i still have the same problem i don't know why but it's the same as before and thank you for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```